# Selecting records in on table based on conditions from another table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, join, scope

In a rails application I am working on I have the following setup:

```
class Volunteer < AR::Base
  has_many :engagements
end

class Engagement < AR::Base
  belongs_to :volunteer
end
```

I am trying to select all volunteers who are not engaged on a particular date or between date ranges:

```
scope :not_engaged_on, lambda { |q| joins(:engagements).where(["engagements.date != ?", q])}

scope :not_engaged_between, lambda { |s, e| joins(:engagements).where(["engagements.date NOT BETWEEN ? AND ?", s, e]) }
```

These scopes I am merging along with other scopes to filter volunteers.

The above scope `:not_engaged_between` produces the following SQL:

```
SELECT "volunteers".* FROM "volunteers" INNER JOIN "accounts" ON "accounts"."user_id" = "volunteers"."id" AND "accounts"."user_type" = 'Volunteer' INNER JOIN "engagements" ON "engagements"."volunteer_id" = "volunteers"."id" WHERE (accounts.activation_state = 'active') AND (engagements.date NOT BETWEEN '2012-07-30' AND '2012-08-04')
```

The problem is a Volunteer might not have any engagements till now and in that case the query totally ignores those volunteers. How can I make return all volunteers even if they don't have any engagements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `not exists` to do this. This syntax is a bit heavy on SQL, maybe there's a better arel-way to do it.

```
scope :not_engaged_on, lambda { |q| where(["NOT EXISTS (SELECT ID from engagements WHERE engagements.date = ? AND volunteer_id = volunteers.id)", q])}

scope :not_engaged_between, lambda { |s, e| where(["NOT EXISTS (SELECT ID from engagements WHERE engagements.date BETWEEN ? AND ? AND volunteer_id = volunteers.id)", s, e]) }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, throwing NoMethodError: undefined method `default_scoped?' for #<Arel::Nodes::Not:0xcfc1b04>. Any ideas??

Comment: Ok edited my answer. May not be the best syntax, but it should do the job

Comment: thanks for your help. Somehow, exists.not syntax and NOT EXISTS was not working for me. Had to do this to make it work: scope :not_engaged_between, lambda { |s, e| joins("LEFT JOIN engagements e ON e.volunteer_id = volunteers.id AND e.date NOT BETWEEN '#{s}' AND '#{e}'").where(["e.volunteer_id IS NULL"]) }, which would generate the SQL as suggested by @Erwin. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Since I am building scopes and merging them before running the query, this method works better for me now, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

@Anthony already mentioned `NOT EXISTS`. The other option is a [`LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM) + check for existence (`e.volunteer_id IS NULL`):

```
SELECT v.*
FROM   volunteers       v
JOIN   accounts         a ON a.user_id = v.id
LEFT  JOIN engagements e ON e.volunteer_id = v.id
                        AND e.date BETWEEN '2012-07-30' AND '2012-08-04'
WHERE  a.user_type = 'Volunteer'
AND    a.activation_state = 'active'
AND   e.volunteer_id IS NULL;
```

You have to move the condition `e.date BETWEEN '2012-07-30' AND '2012-08-04'` to the join clause in this case.

Use another `LEFT JOIN` for `accounts`, if it may be missing, too. But it seems you do want to check for `user_type` and `activation_state`.

Comment: Thanks. It works, I had to define it like this to generate the desired SQL: scope :not_engaged_between, lambda { |s, e| joins("LEFT JOIN engagements e ON e.volunteer_id = volunteers.id AND e.date NOT BETWEEN '#{s}' AND '#{e}'").where(["e.volunteer_id IS NULL"]) }. Thanks again!!